# Angular 2.0 final release Issue on filter and animation combined

Tags: angularjs, animation, typescript1.8

In Angular 2 i was doing a sample app. App has 2 components under same module Product module is listing the product in the grid/table using the component named product-list.component.ts . When a product is selected the view is changed through routing to another component - product-detail.component.ts.

In detail view / component there is a back button to navigate to product-list view/component and when clicked, the list view was loading the list of product in the grid as expected along with filter applied with default value.

The above filter was working until i applied animation on Back button.
The animation has a callback handler for animation done(waiting for animation to complete before navigating to list view). In animation finish i am calling router.navigate('/product').

Application is navigating well from Product-detail to product-list view /component but filter is not getting called.

Filter is called only when user interacts with it.

Below is code snippets only relevant code
1. Product-list.component.ts and Product-list.component.html

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {IProduct} from "./product";
import {ProductService} from "./product.service";
import {Input, trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from "@angular/core";


@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/products/product-list.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('flyInOut', [
            state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
            transition('void => *', [
                style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
                animate(1000)
            ]),
            transition('* => void', [
                animate(1000, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
            ])
        ])
    ]

})

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit{
    pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;
    showImage:boolean = false;
    products: IProduct[];
    listFilter = "cart";
    errorMessage = "";
    productState = "void";

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService){
    }
    toggleImage():void{
       this.showImage = !this.showImage;
       this.productState = this.showImage ? "in": "void";
    }
    ngOnInit():void{
        console.log('Inside Init Angular Component Life cycle hook');
        // this.products = this._productService.getProduct();
        //this.listFilter = "cart";
        this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                       error =>this.errorMessage = <any> error);
    }
    onRatingClicked(message: string):void{
        this.pageTitle = 'Product List' + message;
    }
}
```

```html
  <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor='let product of products | productFilter: listFilter'>
                    
                    <td><a [routerLink]="['/product', product?.productId]">   {{product?.productName}}</a></td>                   
                    <td>{{product?.productCode | lowercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{product?.price | currency:'INR':true:'1.2-2'}}</td>
             </tbody>
```

2. Product-detail.component.ts and  Product-detail.component.html

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

import {Input, trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router }  from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-detail.component.html',
    animations: [
        trigger('backButtonAnimation', [
            state('details', style({
                backgroundColor: '#eee',
                transform: 'scale(1)'
            })),
            state('list',   style({
                backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
                transform: 'scale(1.2)'
            })),
            transition('list => details', animate('100ms ease-in')),
            transition('details => list', animate('200ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]

})

export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = "Product Details";
    productState: string = "details";
    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute , private _router: Router){
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.pageTitle += `: ${id}`;
        });
    }
    toggleState(): void{
        if(this.productState == "list"){
            this.productState = "details"
        }else{
            this.productState = "list"
        }
    }
    onBack(): void{
        this.toggleState();
    }
    animationStarted($event):void{

    }
    animationDone($event): void{
      if($event.fromState== "void" && $event.toState== "details"){
          return;
      }
        this._router.navigate(['/products']);
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="onBack()" (@backButtonAnimation.start)='animationStarted($event)' (@backButtonAnimation.done)='animationDone($event)' [@backButtonAnimation] = "productState">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>Back
        </a>
    </div>
```

Below is my custom filter

```js
    import {PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";
    import {IProduct} from "./product";
    import {Pipe} from "@angular/core";
    
    @Pipe({
        name: 'productFilter'
    })
    
    export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
        transform(value: IProduct[], args: string[]): IProduct[] {
            let filterby = args[0] ? args[0].toLowerCase() : null;
            return filterby ? value.filter((product: IProduct) => product.productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterby)!=-1) : value;
        }
    }
```

NOTE - Code will not run in editor as it doesn't support angular 2.0 right now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: IProduct[], filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filterBy ? value.filter((product: IProduct) =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) : value;
    }

}
```